# Call to undefined function imagettftext()

Tags: php, gd, freetype

I don't have experience with PHP but I am trying to run a php file on my macOS Sierra High 10.13.2. I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined function imagettftext()
```

I have both GD and Freetype installed. What is the problem?

```
for ( $i = 0; $i < strlen( $word ); $i++ ) {
            $font = $this->fonts[array_rand( $this->fonts )];
            $font = $this->normalize_path( $font );

            imagettftext( $im, $this->font_size, mt_rand( -12, 12 ), $x,
                $this->base[1] + mt_rand( -2, 2 ), $fg, $font, $word[$i] );
            $x += $this->font_char_width;
        }
```

Comment: share your code please

Comment: otherwise , are you sure that the GD library and the  FreeType library exist ?

Comment: How could we possibly know what the problem is without your code? Please share it and we will do our best to assist you.

Comment: @Sanguinary updated!

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI I tried to install Freetype using brew and it said that it was already installed. 'php -m' revealed that GD is there. Btw, I added the code to my question

Comment: let's do that , create a new file php and call the phpinfo() function on it . open the page and see if is enabled or not .

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI 
GD Support => enabled
GD Version => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => 9 compatible
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.6.20
WBMP Support => enabled
XBM Support => enabled